# Your Mac OS X startup disk has no more space available for application memory

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac

The error message given in the title is perhaps the most incredibly annoying message I have ever had the mispleasure of reading.  I thought my "startup disk" was the CDRom that has the image of the OS, and I have no idea how this has any bearing on memory, but I think the message is actually telling me that my hard drive is full.  However, df -h says:

```
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   232Gi  188Gi   44Gi    82%    /
devfs          123Ki  123Ki    0Bi   100%    /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%    /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%    /home
```

And

```
$ df -i
Filesystem    512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   486717952 394866752  91339200    82% 49422342 11417400   81%   /
devfs                228       228         0   100%      652        0  100%   /dev
map -hosts             0         0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home          0         0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /home
```

Can anyone explain what that error message is supposed to mean?  For background, this error message used to come up fairly regularly and it looked like chrome was consuming all of the available swap so the default strategy adopted was to restart chrome.  (We used to reboot machines, now we restart our browser.  Progress!)  After a few weeks of the annoyance, I cleared out a bunch of files and made space.  This message started coming up again, and without really thinking or taking any time to investigate, I would just restart chrome, consider switching back to Firefox, and carry on.  Today, I restarted chrome and got the error message again 10 minutes later, and it reappears immediately when closed.  At one point, the handy 'force kill' window suggested that finder was not responsive.  Is it possible that finder is stuck with stale information about the status of the disk and is repeatedly opening up the 'force kill' window with this error message because it is foobar?

Comment: Have you checked inode space (i.e. df -i)?

Comment: "CDRom that has the image of the OS" ...What??

Comment: @Tetsujin When the computer was purchased, it came with a disk (it was probably a DVD rather than a CDRom, but it's long lost) that had an image of the OS on it which could be used to reinstall the system.  If that's not called a startup disk, I don't know what it's called.

Comment: That's an 'Install Disk'. The 'Startup Disk' is the one you are currently booted from. Windows equivalent, 'C Drive' which is always C even if you swap boot drives.

Comment: If 'Startup Disk' refers to /dev/disk0s2, then why am I getting this error message?  (Even after reboot, with plenty of inodes and space available, I'm still getting the error.)